# Unable to run Strongloop Loopback on Amazon ec2 instance from browser

Tags: amazon-ec2, loopbackjs, strongloop

I'm running Strongloop Loopback from Amazon ec2 instance.  I've installed node and have setup a loopback application via the command line on my ec2 instance.  I've also added a model.  When I go to deploy arc "slc arc" I get this message "StrongLoop Arc is running here: http://localhost:42099/#/
NOTICE: Arc seems to have been launched from a remote connection. Depending on your network setup, Arc may not be accessible using the address above."

The documentation says that I should run it using my ec2 ip which I try like this: http://my-ip-here:42099/#/ no success.  I also try this ec2-my-ip-here.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com:42099/#/ also no success.

I went into my security groups and made inbound rule "All traffic" Port range all.  Still nothing.

I went into server/config.json and changed the ip from 0.0.0.0 to my ec2 ip to see if that would work and nothing also.  I also tried running it and just testing explorer and it didn't work.  Neither arc nor explorer.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Arc appears to be binding to localhost only by default. Try running it as `HOST=0.0.0.0 slc arc` and then hitting the displayed port on your instance IP like you have been trying.